# Get writing language of "uitextview" iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, right-to-left

How can i get writing language of uitextview?
or
how can i know uitextview is right to left or left to right in current state?

Comment: Those are two entirely different questions. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: it's not important, any answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[textView baseWritingDirectionForPosition:[textView beginningOfDocument] inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward] == UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft
```

Should return true if the `UITextView` is right-to-left, and false otherwise.

Further documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/baseWritingDirectionForPosition%3ainDirection%3a), if you need it!

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your other question, you can get the keyboard language used from `UITextInputMode` docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks Madivad, it's good answer, i thought method like this dosent exist in iOS sdk :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked better for me

```
[NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:self.textView.textInputMode.primaryLanguage] == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft
```