# iOS: Getting UITextView language

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to detect the current keyboard input method on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860553/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-current-keyboard-input-method-on-the-iphone)
>   [Get writing language of “uitextview” iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433733/get-writing-language-of-uitextview-iphone)

How to get the current editing language of a UITextView object? I mean the CURRENT language of a UITextView keyboard

I don't have other words to say but the question editor requires some more text here lol

Comment: instead of giving me a thumb down, try to make the question editor more intelligent!

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032116/showing-iphone-keyboard-in-different-languages-based-on-user-input et. al.

Comment: I don't see any relevance, I want to GET, he wants to SET

Comment: I see it that it isnt possible either .. it isnt a dup, its RELATED ^^ you dont know about the keyboard. as said 'the user controls the keyboard'

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the language used by the device that's accessing the textview? Couldn't you just get the language of the system? You could use:

`NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];`

(Not my code, found it here: [Getting current device language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910244/getting-current-device-language-in-ios) )

Edit: actually this is what you're after `UITextInputMode` you can read the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: No, I mean the CURRENT language of UITextView keyboard

Comment: In that case, you are after `UITextInputMode`

Comment: I hate to say it, but exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860553/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-current-keyboard-input-method-on-the-iphone

Comment: here is a link to the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Has the above answered your question? I could use the rep points :-)

Comment: yes, exactly what I needed. Thank you. Please edit the answer post to the information in the comments